# std::mutex and condition_variable cannot access private member inside class

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I have done some googling and seen similar questions on stack overflow regarding this issue but am having trouble understanding the cause/solution to deal with it. Given the following class which is declared in ThreadPool.hpp I am getting the following 2 errors:

Error   1   error C2248: 'std::mutex::mutex' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::mutex'  c:\users\jesse\documents\school\summer semester 2012\concurrent processing\project 2\ultra_grep v2\ultra_grep\threadpool.hpp    39  1   ultra_grep2

Error   2   error C2248: 'std::condition_variable::condition_variable' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::condition_variable'   c:\users\jesse\documents\school\summer semester 2012\concurrent processing\project 2\ultra_grep v2\ultra_grep\threadpool.hpp    39  1   ultra_grep2

```
class ThreadPool
{
private:
std::queue<std::string> _consoleTasks;
std::queue<std::tr2::sys::path> _tasks;
std::map<std::string, std::vector<GrepMatch>> _grepMatches;
int _nThreads, _fileMatches, _totalMatches, _workingThreads;
std::vector<thread> _threads;
Arguments _args;
std::mutex _taskMutex, _wakeMutex, _consoleMutex, _threadCountMutex;
std::condition_variable _wakeCondition;

public:
ThreadPool( int threads, Arguments args );
~ThreadPool() {};
void GrepFunc();
void ConsoleFunc();
void SearchFile( std::string );
void SearchFileVerbose( std::string );
void DisplayGrepResults();

queue<std::tr2::sys::path> Tasks() { return _tasks; }

};
```

and the code that is implemented inside of ThreadPool.cpp:

```
#include "ThreadPool.hpp"

using namespace std;
namespace fs = std::tr2::sys;

ThreadPool::ThreadPool( int threads, Arguments args )
: _nThreads( threads ), _args( args ), _fileMatches( 0 ), _totalMatches( 0 ), _workingThreads( 0 )
{

for( int i = 0; i < _nThreads; ++i )
{
        _threads.push_back( thread( &ThreadPool::GrepFunc, this ) );
        _tasks.push( args.root() );
        ++_workingThreads;
        _wakeCondition.notify_one();
}

for( auto& t : _threads )
{
    t.join();
}

DisplayGrepResults();
}

void ThreadPool::GrepFunc()
{
// implement a barrier()

while( !_workingThreads )
{
    { unique_lock<mutex> lk( _wakeMutex );
    _wakeCondition.wait( lk ); }

    while( !_tasks.empty() )
    {
        fs::path task;
        bool gotTask = false;
        {
            lock_guard<mutex> tl( _taskMutex );
            if( !_tasks.empty() )
            {
                { lock_guard<mutex> tc( _threadCountMutex );
                ++_workingThreads; }
                task = _tasks.front();
                _tasks.pop();
                gotTask = true;
            }
        }

        if( gotTask )
        {
            if( fs::is_directory( task ) )
            {
                for( fs::directory_iterator dirIter( task ), endIter; dirIter != endIter; ++dirIter )
                {
                    if( fs::is_directory( dirIter->path() ) )
                    {
                        { lock_guard<mutex> tl( _taskMutex );
                        _tasks.push( dirIter->path() ); }
                        _wakeCondition.notify_one();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        for( auto& e : _args.extensions() )
                        {
                            if( !dirIter->path().extension().compare( e ) )
                            {
                                { lock_guard<mutex> tl( _taskMutex );
                                _tasks.push( dirIter->path() ); }
                                _wakeCondition.notify_one();
                                //SearchFile( dirIter->path() );
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for( auto& e : _args.extensions() )
                {
                    if( !task.extension().compare( e ) )
                    {
                        if( _args.is_verbose() )
                            SearchFile( task );
                        else
                            SearchFileVerbose( task );
                    }
                }
            }

            { lock_guard<mutex> tc( _threadCountMutex) ;
            --_workingThreads; }
        }
    }
}
}

void ThreadPool::SearchFileVerbose( string path )
{
fstream file;
file.open( path );

if( !file )
{
    // error handling
}
else
{
    { 
        lock_guard<mutex> cm( _consoleMutex );
        cout << "\nGrepping: " << path << endl;

        int lineNumber = 1;
        string line;
        vector<GrepMatch> matches;
        while( getline( file, line ) )
        {
            int lineMatches = 0;
            sregex_token_iterator end;
            for (sregex_token_iterator i(line.cbegin(), line.cend(), _args.regular_expression() );
                i != end;
                ++i)
            {
                ++lineMatches;
            }

            if( lineMatches > 0 )
            {
                GrepMatch match = GrepMatch( lineNumber, lineMatches, line );
                matches.push_back( match );
                cout << "Matched " << lineMatches << ": " << path << " [" << lineNumber << "] " << line << endl; 
            }

            ++lineNumber;
        }

        if( !matches.empty() )
        {
            _grepMatches[ path ] = matches;
        }
    }
}
}
```

I am getting errors on both the mutex and the condition_variable saying that they cannot access private members declared inside the class. It is my understanding that this is referring to the copy constructor? Although I don't understand why that comes into play cause I don't see where I am trying to make a copy as they are simply private members of the class.

As per the initial comments I only instantiate a single instance of ThreadPool and it is not copied anywhere. The only times I am trying to touch the mutexes at all are in the .cpp implementation of my class.

Can anyone help me gain a better understanding of why this is happening?

For those interested here is the compiler output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ultra_grep2, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  ultra_grep_main.cpp
1>  Unknown compiler version - please run the configure tests and report the results
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\school\summer semester 2012\concurrent processing\project 2\ultra_grep v2\ultra_grep\threadpool.hpp(39): error C2248: 'std::mutex::mutex' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::mutex'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\mutex(116) : see declaration of 'std::mutex::mutex'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\mutex(107) : see declaration of 'std::mutex'
1>          This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'ThreadPool::ThreadPool(const ThreadPool &)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\mutex(116) : see declaration of 'std::mutex::mutex'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\mutex(107) : see declaration of 'std::mutex'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\mutex(116) : see declaration of 'std::mutex::mutex'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\mutex(107) : see declaration of 'std::mutex'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\mutex(116) : see declaration of 'std::mutex::mutex'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\mutex(107) : see declaration of 'std::mutex'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\school\summer semester 2012\concurrent processing\project 2\ultra_grep v2\ultra_grep\threadpool.hpp(39): error C2248: 'std::condition_variable::condition_variable' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::condition_variable'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\condition_variable(45) : see declaration of 'std::condition_variable::condition_variable'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\condition_variable(30) : see declaration of 'std::condition_variable'
1>          This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'ThreadPool::ThreadPool(const ThreadPool &)'
1>  ThreadPool.cpp
1>  Generating Code...
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Do you ever try making a copy of a `ThreadPool`?

Comment: You should add the code where the error is being triggered as well as the exact error message. Compiler error messages convey much more information than what you vague statement does.

Comment: Alright will add those to the original post. The error is being triggered right on the declaration of the private mutex and condition_variable members of my header file for the ThreadPool class.

Comment: The really frustrating part of all this is that this is my second version of a ThreadPool application for searching files in which I have been doing refactoring to improve speed and performance but in the first version I used both mutexes and condition_variables with no problem at all. Could this have anything to do with having both a  header file and cpp implementation? Seems like a long shot but one of the things I did was break them apart and perhaps that is somehow invoking the copy constructor? Sorry I am so bad with this

Comment: @JesseCarter: You should add the *whole* error message, which most probably contain a couple more lines indicating *what* private member cannot be accessed and *where* the access is required.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas That is the entire error message copy and pasted directly out of visual studio. I can post up the Output too if you would like?

Comment: @Jesse: you don't get another error that says something like: `This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'foo::foo(const foo &)'`?  That would indicate for certain that it's a copy operation that you're not seeing. You may want to try building with MinGW - in situations like this it will give a message such as `C:\temp\test.cpp:29:9: note: synthesized method 'foo& foo::operator=(const foo&)' first required here` that indicates what caused the copy constructor to be invoked (or at least the first such line). Unfortunately, MSVC doesn't seem to give that bit of assistance.

Comment: @JesseCarter: Where are you reading the errors? the IDE might have a summary of errors window, but that is almost never as useful as seeing the compiler output as it happens. The real compiler output contains that line and probably a couple more around with extra information. Even if you get the answer without providing that information, being able to locate and understand error messages is one of the important abilities when developing and in particular in C++.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I will add the compiler output to the original post

Comment: @Jesse: The problematic copy is occurring somewhere in `ultra_grep_main.cpp`, not `ThreadPool.cpp`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is somewhere in:

> 1>  ultra_grep_main.cpp

where the copy constructor of `ThreadPool` is *used*:

> This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'ThreadPool::ThreadPool(const ThreadPool &)'

I am actually surprised that the compiler did not point at what line in the source file the copy constructor is implicitly generated.

In a comment you ask how the copy constructor should look like. A better question is whether it makes sense to make copies of a `ThreadPool` object, and the answer is that in general it doesn't. To improve the error message you could mark the copy constructor as `deleted`, and that way (hopefully) the compiler will produce better error reports as to where the copy is needed:

```
class ThreadPool {
   ThreadPool( ThreadPool const & ) = delete;
// ...
};
```

If your compiler does not support this C++11 feature, the alternative is to *declare* the copy constructor but not define it. That will trigger an access error at the place of use of the copy constructor.

Comment: Thanks for a clear and concise answer this really helped me out. I added the copy constructor to my ThreadPool class and changed the line in my main from ThreadPool threadPool = ThreadPool( args ) to just ThreadPool( args ) and it works now

Answer (score 7):

The problem is what you thought; the compiler-generated copy constructor and assignment operator are failing, because mutex and condition_variable aren't copyable. The compiler still generates code for both in many cases that aren't easy to see, even though you aren't intentionally invoking them. In my experience, this error is usually caused by trying to use the type with a standard library container.

You should probably add an empty private copy constructor and assignment operator, even if you didn't have this issue; I don't think it's ever desirable to try to copy a thread pool.

Comment: Can you show me an example of a copy constructor for the ThreadPool class or point me to an article/site in the right direction? And do I need to do something similar to overload mutex/condition_variable?